# Is there a LaTeX package for Proto-Indo-European laryngeals?

Tags: reference-request, proto-indo-european, latex

I'm including some PIE examples in my Latex-formatted thesis. What font package or predefined symbols will help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [tipa](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package, a general package for typesetting phonetic transcriptions. It has all the stuff you need including the multiple accents. It works with all flavours of LaTeX.

In addition, it comes with a really excellent documentation.

Comment: More info needed here. I've tried tipa and tipx to get some diacritics. 

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{tipx}

Some of the characters in the \textipa{} environment work, and some don't.  For example:

This works:
\textipa{*\|c{k}\r*mt\’om   *bhr\textacutemacron{a}t\=er}

This doesn't:  \textipa{*bhr\’=at\=er}

According to the tipa manual they should both work.  I've fooled around a bit with prologue and re-read the tipa manual a few times, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @SteveRapaport: The is is pair of braces missing in your not working example, this also works:  `\textipa{*bhr\'{\=a}t\=er}`—but it produces slightly different output than `\textipa{*bhr\textacutemacron{a}t\=er}`.

Answer (score 2):

In text mode, you can simply use the `\textsubscript{}` command to format some text as a subscript. So h<sub>3</sub>, for instance, can be made with `h\textsubscript{3}`.

More problematic might be symbols like the palatal stops, *ḱ, *ǵ, and *ǵʰ, or accented long vowels, like *ā́, *ḗ, and *ṓ. There aren't, to the best of my knowledge, pre-composed glyphs of these, so you'll almost certainly want to be using [XeTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex?lang=en) with the [`fontspec` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en) (and a font containing the appropriate glyphs) to write these characters.

Comment: I agree that the palatal stops and accented long vowels are hard to construct. To try this answer out, I'd want to know what fonts contain the appropriate glyphs. Hints?

Comment: I would say there are almost too many fonts nowadays to even start naming some. SIL has a family of fonts that looks okay, renders these glyphs correctly, and are widely used in linguistics (Charis, Doulos, Gentium, etc.): http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IPAhome

Other options that I think are nice looking include the Linux Libertine family of fonts, however, they are not used as widely: http://www.linuxlibertine.org/

Lucida Sans Unicode is not the prettiest font, but has been distributed with Windows by default for some time now.